# Probability with graphs and recurrence relation?

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I am tackling a problem which deals with random traversal/walk on a $K_5$ graph ($5$-complete), the walk starts at some vertex $x$ and $y$ is another vertex, $P_n$ denotes the probability after $n$ steps of the random traversal, I know that $P_0$ = $0$ and $P_1$ = $1/4$. Then I am told that $P_n$ = ($1$-$P_{n-1}$)/4 for $n>=1$. Could someone give me a hint as to how to approach this? I do know that since the degree of each vertex is 4, the probability of going to another vertex is 1/4.

Comment: You haven't fully defined $P_n$, but shouldn't $P_0=0$, not $P_0=1$?

Comment: thank you, I believe that should be $0$, that should be a typo in the question given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that after $n-1$ steps we are at $y$ is $P_{n-1}$. So the probability we are **not** at $y$ is $1-P_{n-1}$.

**Given** that we are not at $y$ after $n-1$ steps, the probability we are at $y$ after $1$ more step is $\frac{1}{4}$. It follows that $P_n=(1-P_{n-1})\cdot\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: could you elaborate on the "given we are not at $y$ after $n-1$ steps" ?

Comment: Given that we are not at $y$ after $n-1$ steps, by symmetry the next step takes us to $y$ is $\frac{1}{4}$. Is this the part that requires clarification? It follows from the fact our graph is $K_5$, and presumably at any stage we choose one of the $4$ vertices we are not standing on to go to, with all choices equally likely. And the probability we are not at $y$ after $n-1$ steps is $1$ minus the probability we are at $y$, so it is $1-P_{n-1}$. (More)

Comment: (More) To put it another way, in order to be at $y$ after $n$ steps we must (i) be on a vertex other than $y$ after step $n-1$ and (ii) jump to $y$ on the next step. The probability of (i) is $1-P_{n-1}$, and if (i) has happened, the probability of (ii) is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: thanks, that clarifies it. I also added a comment about deducing $P_n$ above this post, could you possibly give me a hint as to how to approach it?

Comment: Since you are given the formula, induction can be used to verify it. But I would not do it that way. Our recurrence is $P_n=-\frac{P_{n-1}}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$. You probably have worked with such linear recurrences. It is easy to verify that the general solution of the homogeneous recurrence $P_n=-\frac{P_{n-1}}{4}$ is $A(-1/4)^n$. Find also a particular solution of the inhomogeneous recurrence, and then meet the initial condition. A more basic way is to write down the first $5$ or so terms and you will see a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you, I think I know how to approach it now. Also for the first part, I tried to prove $P_n$ = $(1- P_{n-1})/4$ with induction, but it didn't work, is it possible to prove this using induction?

Comment: I don't think the recurrence can be proved by induction. The natural approach is the one in the answer.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much!